# -moz-transform: scale() low image quality

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I want to expand my images onclick (http://css-tricks.com/expanding-images-html5/). But I have a problem. Screenshots:

http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9841/030xu.png - in Chrome

http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/13/0225/h_1361796223_3798534_0de4e000c5.png - in Firefox 19.

How can I repare a low-quality image in Firefox?
Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

This problem fixed in Firefox 20.